# DTO to TypeScript generator

Tags: c#, typescript

I have a C# library (assembly) which contains a set of DTOs which I use to populate my knockout models (TypeScript).

I would like to make sure that the mapping between the JSON data and the ViewModel is correct.

Are there  a tool which can generate TypeScript classes from my C# classes? Something like T4 or similar (or just a command line tool which is run as a POST-build event)?

(Note that the TypeScript files must be placed in another project than the DTO assembly)

Comment: would this do the job - you can specify a custom build that'll run from the command line - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/SamTomato/visual-studio-2010-typescript-build-tool/

Comment: @RachelGallen: No, it transforms typescript to javascript. I want c# to typescript.

Comment: no it doesn't it has c sharp as an option and it does do it the way you want. have another look

Comment: I looked again and still do not see how to run `tsc.exe` to generate .ts from .cs/.dll. If you do know how to do it, why don't you write an answer?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There are lots of projects that do this. Your best bet *today* will be to assess which option is still actively maintained, and meets *your* requirements

- TypeLITE : http://type.litesolutions.net/
- TypeScriptModelsGenerator : https://www.nuget.org/packages/TypeScriptModelsGenerator
- NSwag : https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag
- ToTypeScriptD : https://github.com/ToTypeScriptD/ToTypeScriptD
- TypeScripter : http://cjlpowers.github.io/TypeScripter/
- MTT : https://github.com/CodySchrank/MTT
- TypeGen : https://github.com/jburzynski/TypeGen

## Note

The world is strongly going TypeScript for both front and backend. Hence the diverse state of cross language tooling.

Comment: TypeLITE [doesn't support .NET Core](https://bitbucket.org/LukasKabrt/typelite/issues/123/not-working-with-core-10)

Comment: The question is closed, so I'm writing my answer here. Try [TypeWriter](https://github.com/frhagn/Typewriter), a Visual Studio extensions that generates TypeScript files from C# code using TypeScript Templates. Check out [an example](http://frhagn.github.io/Typewriter/pages/examples.html) for accessing Web API controllers in Angular.

Comment: i've published a package on [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TypeScriptModelsGenerator) that can do the trick with reflection. You can scope models with regex of typenames  or NameSpaces. It's a .Net Standard 2.0 class library.

Comment: "The world is strongly going TypeScript for both front and backend. Hence the diverse state of cross language tooling."

There's deno - a Typescript runtime from node creator - https://github.com/denoland/deno . But I have to disagree because many backends run on .NET or golang or python and even rust

Comment: And now there's also Blazor, so you can do full-stack in C# with some JS interop if needed and it compiles down to web assembly

Comment: From this list, TypeScriptModelsGenerator worked best for me. TypeGen looks promising too but it doesn't work for me currently

Comment: This is what I use. If you want to add it to your build step then just use the cli.https://github.com/AdrianWilczynski/CSharpToTypeScript/blob/master/src/CSharpToTypeScript.CLITool/README.md

Answer (score 14):

Check out the open-source project [NSwag](http://nswag.org): With the GUI, you can select a .NET class from an existing assembly and generate the TypeScript interface for it.

[image: screenshot]

There is also a command line tool and support for T4 templates as well as generation of client code for Web API controllers...

Comment: I wanted to generate types for POCOs only from .NET framework 4 library. NSwagStudio is freezing when I try to generate - it generates forever.

Answer (score 8):

There is a new library called [TypeScriptD](https://github.com/ToTypeScriptD/ToTypeScriptD) which will create `.d.ts` files for your .NET classes.

This can be run as a command and works for .NET or winmd.

Comment: but it can't be installed through nuget.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar need but found the existing projects were too limiting in one way or another (buggy, no generics, no methods, etc.) so I ended up rolling my own (http://cjlpowers.github.io/TypeScripter/). In my case I was dealing with ServiceContract/DataContract types on the server and needed .d.ts files to aid client side development. The solution is extensible should you need to tweak it.