# ASP .Net Core Dto's and Controllers to typescript classes & interfaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, typescript, typelite

My idea consists of two main elements:

1. Take C# Dto's (Data-tranfer-objects) and convert them into typescript interfaces to ensure client-side models are in sync with server side.
2. Take ASP .Net core controller endpoints and convert them to typescript classes that uses a http-service or similar. Again, to ensure client-side requests are in sync with the server.

And whenever a change have been made to a controller or dto, the typescript generated items should then refresh to stay in sync while developing.

I have done some research and found the following Stack Overflow threads and other sources:

- [DTO to TypeScript generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656406/dto-to-typescript-generator) which suggest using the [TypeLite](http://type.litesolutions.net/) library, which seems great, but according to the documentation, this either requires a [TsClass] Attribute or a reference to class on startup. But, since the project structure I'm using is setup so that all dto's is located in a *.Dtos namespace, I'm kinda missing a TypeScript.Definitions().ForNameSpace(). Also, this only solves the first idea/problem.
- [Swashbuckly.AspNetCore](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) Would allow me to generate swagger documentation from both the controllers and dto's, and then the task would be to someway interpret the swagger documentation and create typescript classes and interfaces from that. The cons is that as far as i can read, this requires me to startup the server, which if possible i would like to avoid since it would make it hard to update on file change.

FYI, this is a new project I'm about to start, so there's no legacy code to update, also, all of the ASP .NET Core endpoints will return IActionResult to enable the return of Ok(), BadRequest() and so on. So to get the return model would in my mind be hard, since there's not an easy way to get the dto it produces, if any.

So, i have thought of the following solutions that solves both problems:

1. Create a separate package/application that uses the [Swashbuckly](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) lib and generates the models and controllers without starting up the whole server.
2. Create annotations on every endpoint, something along the lines of [Produces(SomeDto)], where after i would create a small console-application that uses reflection to get information and generate typescript from that. This would of cause requires developers to keep this information in sync, so in my mind there's kinda duplicate information.

But, both of these solutions would not auto-update on C# source file save.

Looking forward to any discussions/suggestions.

Comment: I've been evaluating something similar.  I will warn you that if you go the TypeLite path, it does not currently support .NET Core; however, I found TypeLite to be the best solution in .NET 4.  While it may not offer a namespace loading pattern, it uses a recursive identification to determine all of the referenced attribute models.  So if you have one or two top-level models, you can simply reference those and all of the child attribute types down to the lowest level model will be loaded as well.

Answer (score 8):

Considering your first point, I made a C# DTO to typescript interface generator that uses MSBUILD tasks so its completely independent of your workflow.  It also just does it from the source which makes it a bit less stable but you don't have to make any template files.

Find it [here](https://github.com/CodySchrank/MTT) or just search for MTT on nuget

Comment: Awesome, thanks for MTT. Was looking for a solution with a custom output directory (which is outside the Visual Studio solution).

Comment: Thank you!! I've looked at a stack of these with various success, but nothing really hit the mark. Yours is elegant and simple enough to extend. Perfect :-)

Answer (score 3):

In case you are still looking....  I think Typewriter http://frhagn.github.io/Typewriter/ is your solution.  You can generate templates specifying what and how to transform.

It doesn't meet all of my needs only because I need a tool to dynamically generate a complicated folder structure, but that's coming in their v2 roadmap.

Besides that, it does a lot of heavy lifting and is pretty easy to configure.